# Using jQuery or CSS to swap around list items - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list which is perfect for desktop however I need to move them around for mobile - they show images but need to order them differently for mobile and wondering if it is possible to do in CSS or jQuery.

As you can see from the screenshots, desktop does left left, right right which is great but on mobile I need to have left, right, left, right etc.. I cannot modify markup as it is generated in the Smarty template, so need to do a solution with CSS or jQuery.

I have no idea how this could be done though.

For **Desktop** works fine, like this:

```
ITEM 1 | ITEM 2
ITEM 3 | ITEM 4
ITEM 5 | ITEM 6
ITEM 7 | ITEM 8
```

[image]

For **Mobile**, currently works like this:

```
ITEM 1
ITEM 2
ITEM 3
ITEM 4
ITEM 5
ITEM 6
ITEM 7
ITEM 8
```

[image]

**But, I want instead to be like this for mobile**:

```
ITEM 1
ITEM 3
ITEM 2
ITEM 4
ITEM 5
ITEM 7
ITEM 6
ITEM 8
```

[image]

Html list:

```
<ul class="subcategories clearfix">
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/butterfly-sofa-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?t=1437997789" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/avatar-lounger-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-avatar.jpg?t=1437997872" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/twin-couch-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-twin.jpg?t=1437998079" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/versa-table-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-versa.jpg?t=1437998061" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/acoustic-sofa-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-acoustic.jpg?t=1437998265" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/pet-lounger-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-pet.jpg?t=1437996755" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/wing-ottoman-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/4/category-pane-wing-ottoman.jpg?t=1437998482" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/fiorenze-leather-bean-bags/">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  "    src="/images/detailed/3/category-panel-fiorenze.jpg?t=1437998353" alt="" title=""  />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, then they have a push/pull mechanism.

Comment: Can you add your currect CSS?

Comment: CSS is using a massive framework so will be a lot to add in, it is based on bootstrap though so could do the push and pull - i guess would need to do with JS right? do you know best way to do this?

Comment: Get rid of the giant images and show us the actual HTML. We can't help you without it.

Comment: The html is just a normal list like above.....  but with classes and images wrapped in a link nothing special.

Comment: Can you change the HTML at all?

Comment: I think you should have different images for desktop/laptops and devices. so the website will load quicker

Comment: Again that i cannot do, it comes from the CMS and only one image can be set for the list currently - normally i would do this but given the live date not possible to code tones on addons for this.

Comment: @James checkout my simple answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet, another CSS solution for the mobile version:

```css
ul {
    line-height: 1em;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n - 2) {
    top: 1em; /* move down */
}

ul li:nth-child(4n - 1) {
    top: -1em; /* move up */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ITEM 1</li>
    <li>ITEM 2</li>
    <li>ITEM 3</li>
    <li>ITEM 4</li>
    <li>ITEM 5</li>
    <li>ITEM 6</li>
    <li>ITEM 7</li>
    <li>ITEM 8</li>
</ul>
```

Keep it simple. The idea is to swap rows every 4th element.
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2e796d8/4/)** with your specific problem.

---

**[Here is a responsive design solution](http://jsfiddle.net/q2e796d8/6/)**. I am using translations to swap rows, since the height of those images are unknown.
Using a `vw` unit allows the site to respond to viewport width changes. This naturally works for all screen sizes.

I've also reformatted you markup to git rid of the whitespaces between each `li`. This way all images are glued together without margins.
Since each `li` is `inline-block`, the following renders a white space between each element:

```
<li>
  image1
</li>
<li>
  image2
</li>
```

So, what I did was changing to

```
<li>
  image1
</li><li>    <!-- No spaces between each li tag -->
  image2
</li>
```

Comment: Good solution here, thanks mate! anyway you think we can work out the image height and set the margins as its responsive right? slightly differs depending on mobile i guess..... maybe some jQuery to get image height and set? whats your thoughts?

Comment: Ahh was wondering why some bottom margins were bigger than others and would explain why, on dev site i actually apply 10px bottom but ill have a look in a moment to see if remove the white space. The markup is looped in a smarty template so might have to do the markup inline... ill have a play but was going to ask if you knew why but now i know so thanks mate! been a great help! +1 dude!

Comment: I removed the whitespace in the loop but still seems the same, literally the whole ul > li > li > li > li > /ul is all inline in the source and still no go, but having a play i noticed a display block on the li img so i changed that to inline for mobile and worked, reverted the changes i done making the li inline and removing the whitespace and also worked so all good now :) thanks again mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with plain CSS. You have a logo inside your lists, in my example I use a `<span>`. So the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 1</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 2</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 3</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 4</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 5</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 6</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 7</li>
    <li><span>logo</span>ITEM 8</li>
</ul>
```

So what we want is to swap the logo of every to items to the left or right. So we float them left or right.

Then we add a media query. When the screen gets smaller (in my example under 600px) the list-items get wider and every other logo gets floated left or right.

All together looks the CSS like this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 4%;
}
li span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
}
li:nth-child(4n) span, 
li:nth-child(4n-1) span {
    float: right;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    li {
        width: 90%;
    }    
    li:nth-child(odd) span {
        float: left;
    } 
    li:nth-child(even) span {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2e796d8/)
Resize the result window to see the "mobile view".

Comment: That will work great im sure, just tried your demo! thanks mate!! ill get it integrated but great work! thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh actually would that work with what i just have? i upated the markup above. i just uses 1 image for each.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q2e796d8/1/ - i update with the html source - is it still possible using that source code?

Comment: The black box is fixe don the image yes, hence why wanted to use js or css to change the li order. Has to be jus the single image like it is.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos, I was working on an alternativ solution... you gave it, was exactly what I was thinking as well :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use media screen. It'll use different CSS depending on the width of the device. Try adding media screen and changing the width of the elements for a smaller device width:

```
@media screen 
and (device-width: 320px) 
and (device-height: 640px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
 li{
    width:100%;
   }
}
```

For example.

Comment: I already have that for mobile, which is placing the images fine at 100% but i need ot change the order